# How to load local audio files dynamically with expo av

Tags: react-native

i have a bunch of audio files local to my app and i want to load them dynamically based on a component's state, the only way i found to load the audio with expo av is to use "require", but this method keeps returning "invalid call" whenever i try to use a variable of any sort or any template literals in the path string in it.

i tried even storing the paths in a json file and then referrirng to the path directly there and still got the invalid call error.

```
 const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(require(audioPaths['paths'][fileKey]), {}, playbackStatusUpdate);
```

how do you guys go about this issue? my files are local so i can't take advantage of streaming/loading them from network. does expo av offer any alternative to the require method? i need any tips or advice you might have

PS: if you need any more details about the situation please ask me and i will fill you in

Edit: this is how my paths json looks like

```
{
    "paths": [
        "../assets/Records/1.mp3",
        "../assets/Records/2.mp3",
        "../assets/Records/3.mp3",
        "../assets/Records/4.mp3"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is related to audio paths not being declared as `System.registerDynamic`.
you should define paths in JSON like this

```
    "paths": [
        require('./assets/one.mp3'),
        require('./assets/two.mp3'),
        require('./assets/three.mp3'),
    ]
  }
```

and call this without **require**,

`const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(audioPaths['paths'][fileKey], {}, playbackStatusUpdate);`

[here](https://snack.expo.dev/@rohitkhairnar/playing-sounds) is a snack I used

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just a side question wouldn't this cause performance issues if i had a large number of recordings (say 500)?

Comment: yes, considering memory wise, 500 mp3s sounds like a large number

Answer (score 1):

For others facing a similar issue, the file name also cannot have spaces. I changed my file name to use dashes instead of spaces and [the example in the docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/audio/) worked.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically when you want to upload files in a react native app, you will use either formData, or fileupload or react-native-fs or expo-file-system.
I recommend you the expo-file-system since you use expo.
See complete implementation [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/)
But saying `i have a bunch of audio files local to my app` means that your audio files are already uploaded into a directory in your project folder and just you want those audio to be played dynamically using the expo-av `Audio.Sound.createAsync()` with `require()`. This is how I would do that:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';

export default function App() {
  const [sound, setSound] = React.useState();

  async function playSound() {
    console.log('Loading Sound');
    const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync( require('./assets/Hello.mp3')
    );
    setSound(sound);

    console.log('Playing Sound');
    await sound.playAsync();
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    return sound
      ? () => {
          console.log('Unloading Sound');
          sound.unloadAsync();
        }
      : undefined;
  }, [sound]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Play Sound" onPress={playSound} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

This sample is for playing one audio, but in your question you want the audio to be played dynamically. For that you can only use react-native useEffect hook to create a kind of repeatable actions. I would first create a method `playSound` like this:

```
playSound = async () => {
  await Audio.Sound.createAsync( require('' + source);
};
```

Here source is the path to an audio sent as variable and you may want to use function `goToNext()` and `resumePlayList()`  to change the path of source variable like:

```
const goToNext = () => {
  for(let i = 0; i < noGuest; i++){
  source = JsonPath[i];
}
```

Comment: You see the step where you recommend to use source as variable in the require, this is where i'm getting the error, i tried something similar to what you described and i'm still getting ":Invalid call at line 134: require('' + path)"

Comment: @M.KH So I will be necessary to update your question in showing what audioPaths['paths'][fileKey] looks like, and what "invalid call" refers to in the file. eventually you may nee to explain the steps you implemented to achieve this , and where in the steps is the actual problem. For now "invalid call" sounds like a method is not receiving the correct parameter.